# Inkscape clipping a text with path is not working

Tags: inkscape, svg, clipping-mask

I am trying to clip a simple text with a path on Inkscape and is not working.
Here is my text :
[image: text to clip]

Here is my path on top of my original text :

[image: path covering image]

Then I select both, and I click on Object --> Clip --> Define and my orginal text should be completely clipped but here is the result :

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Not sure I understand what you are trying to actually achieve, but strokes are ignored in a clipping path.  I think what you'd need to do is Path  > Stroke to Path, before applying your clipping path. Why are you trying to add a clipping path around text?  It won't actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to make an animation as in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wab7lQKHXL4&t=3s. Your solution is working but I cannot do that because I am using the stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset...

Comment: I just had a look at that tutorial. It seems you may have missed out some steps. I don't know where you have gone wrong. Why don't you leave a comment for the video creator on youtube?  It's really hard to unpick someone else's tutorial.

Comment: I already did and waiting for answer. I do not see what I am missing. Thanks for your replies

Comment: Note that the instructions on the video also say he is using a custom version of Inkscape - so not sure if this will work with the regular Inkscape. Again this is something you need to ask the tutorial creator about. I'm not going to install another version of Inskcape just to find out if the tutorial actually works.

Comment: Yeah... Do you know alternative way to have same result ?

Comment: No, sorry I don't don't really know enough about html5 and SVG animation. Perhaps have a look for a better tutorial that has more in-depth explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Path > Stroke to Path to your red shape. Using a stroke for clipping leaves visible the area which would get filled if the stroke had got a fill color.

EDIT due later comments:

This is useless method in this special case because questioner's animation process doesn't accept it.

Comment: Please see my answer to BillyKerr

Comment: Thanks for your edit, but do you see any reason why it is not working as in the video ? If no, do you know any other way to do it ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm very weak in speaking and writing computer programming languages such as SVG and browser controlling languages.

Comment: (continued) But where are you going to watch the result? Static image in Inkscape looks at least for non-programmers different than a live run in a browser.

Comment: I watch it on a browser yes